# YouTube Subscribe button/link without redirect

Tags: html, javascript, youtube, embed

I want to embed a youtube subscribe button in my webpage. But each time the subscribe button is clicked, it redirects the user to the YouTube app to subscribe. I want the user to stay in my website, but let the user get a pop up window or something like that, to give access.

PS: this isn't a code request question. Just if someone points me in the right direction. I will figure it out. But if someone is willing to share any code, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the user to stay in my website, but let the user get a pop up
>   window or something like that, to give access.

The best approach (arguably) to exercise maximum control (and avoid 3rd-party payload etc.) is to use your own link to Youtube, which can be your own `<button>` or even just a styled `<a>` link.

Then, if you wish to open a link target in a new browser tab, simply use `target="_blank"`.

**e.g.**

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/subscribe-url" title="Subscribe to Youtube" target="_blank">Subscribe to Youtube</a>
```